# Build dictionary from array using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, dictionary

I have a class A containing an array of key/values pairs described by class B. One of the key is called "name". I want to use Linq to build a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` where key of first dictionary is the attribute called "name" in the B array and the value is a second dictionary that contains the key/value pairs of B.

```
public class A
{
    public int a;
    public B[] b;
}

public class B
{
    public string key;
    public string value;
}

A[] a = new A[]
{
    new A { a = 1, b = new B[] { new B { key = "name", value = "n1"}, new B { key = "test", value = "t1" } }, },
    new A { a = 2, b = new B[] { new B { key = "name", value = "n2"}, new B { key = "test", value = "t2" } }, },
};
```

So in fact I would like to build the following dictionary using Linq on array "a":

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> d = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
{
    { "n1",  new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "name", "n1" }, { "test", "t1" } } },
    { "n2",  new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "name", "n2" }, { "test", "t2" } } },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
var dict = a.ToDictionary(
    x => x.b[0].value, 
    y => y.b.ToDictionary(z => z.key, z => z.value)
);
```

The only "fun" part of this LINQ expression is that I had to use up to `z` parameters (`x`, `y`, `z`)... It took me three compilations to get it right (I always name the parameters `x`)

Revised for comment:

```
var dict = a.ToDictionary(
    x => x.b.First(y => y.key == "name").value, 
    y => y.b.ToDictionary(z => z.key, z => z.value)
);
```

Comment: Cool ! The parameter "name" may be randomly placed in the array (not necessarily the first element). How could I modify the expression to cope with this ?

Comment: @user957479 Updated

Comment: Thanks, it always looks so easy when you see the result ;-)